# Rotate First Element with Different Result in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, element

I have an assignment in Python (using Jupyter).

Here it is:

[image]

I need to make a list called *weird* on the 27th line that should results [[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]] if I do xrotateR(weird[0]) function on it.

How can I do this?

The xrotateR function is:

```
def xrotateR(lst) :
    c=lst[-1:]
    lst[:]=c+lst[0:-1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Usually I would ask for your attempt, but I can understand if someone new to Python blanks on this assignment.

Comment: Is there still something unclear?

Answer (score 2):

They want you to put the same list (literally the same object in memory, not just equal lists) in a list of lists.

```
>>> def xrotateR(lst) :
...     c=lst[-1:]
...     lst[:]=c+lst[0:-1]
... 
>>> weird = [[1, 2, 3]]*2
>>> weird
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

We can confirm that the elements of `weird` are not just equal but the same object with the `is` operator.

```
>>> weird[0] is weird[1]
True
```

Thus, `xrotateR` will mutate both entries of `weird`.

```
>>> xrotateR(weird[0])
>>> weird
[[3, 1, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Instantiating such a list is a [common bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly), by the way.

edit: try out [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/) for the visualizations they ask, it will draw the correct diagrams for you. Just make sure you understand them. ;)